# how to build sorted listview in flutter (sort as per dates)

Tags: flutter, date, listview

I want to display a listview from database. The notes stored in 'note' table are displayed successully. I want to display it as per the dates. i.e recent ones at the top and later ones(future ones) below them. if the date is of tomorrow then it should be at the top and day after tomorrow one below it. If the dates are same I want to sort them as per priority. Can anyone please help me.
(If u use any other date and time picker which can accept date and time together would also be helpful). In my case the table calendar only accepts the date. I am storing the date as TEXT(i dont know if its right)
new_note.dart// this is where I add a new note to the database.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';
import 'package:flutter_speed_dial/flutter_speed_dial.dart';
import 'package:smooth_star_rating/smooth_star_rating.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:vers2cts/models/color_dropdown.dart';
import 'package:vers2cts/models/customer_model.dart';
import 'package:vers2cts/models/note_model.dart';
import 'package:vers2cts/services/db_service.dart';
import 'package:vers2cts/utils/form_helper.dart';

class NewNote extends StatefulWidget{
  final NoteModel note;
  final CustomerModel customer;
  NewNote(this.customer,this. note);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return New_NoteState(this.customer,this.note);
  }

}
class New_NoteState extends State<NewNote> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  New_NoteState(this.customer,this.note);
  NoteModel note=new NoteModel();
  CustomerModel customer=new CustomerModel();
  TextEditingController NoteController=TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController custfNameController = TextEditingController();
  DateTime _reminderDate = DateTime.now();
  DateTime _selectedDay = DateTime.now();
  DBService dbService=new DBService();
  double _height;
  double _width;
  dynamic currentTime = DateFormat.jm().format(DateTime.now());

  String _setTime, _setDate;

  String _hour, _minute, _time;

  String dateTime;

  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

  TimeOfDay selectedTime = TimeOfDay(hour: 00, minute: 00);

  TextEditingController _dateController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _timeController = TextEditingController();
  SpeedDial _speedDial(){
    return SpeedDial(
      animatedIcon: AnimatedIcons.add_event,

      animatedIconTheme: IconThemeData(size: 24.0),
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
      curve: Curves.easeInCirc,
      children: [
        SpeedDialChild(
          child: Icon(Icons.location_on,color: Colors.yellow,),
          label: 'Add Location',
        ),
        SpeedDialChild(
          child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_voice),
          label: 'Add voice',

        ),
        SpeedDialChild(
          child: Icon(Icons.attachment_outlined,color :Colors.redAccent),
          label: 'Add File',
        ),
        SpeedDialChild(
          child: Icon(Icons.image,color: Colors.lightBlue,),
          label: 'Add Image',

        ),
      ],
    );
  }
  //for Switch
  bool isSwitched = false;
  var textValue = 'Switch is OFF';

  void toggleSwitch(bool value) {

    if(isSwitched == false)
    {
      setState(() {
        isSwitched = true;
        note.rmnd_ind=1;
      });
    }
    else
    {
      setState(() {
        isSwitched = false;
        note.rmnd_ind=0;
      });
    }
  }
  Future<Null> _selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
    final TimeOfDay picked = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: selectedTime,
    );
    if (picked != null)
      setState(() {
        selectedTime = picked;
        _hour = selectedTime.hour.toString();
        _minute = selectedTime.minute.toString();
        _time = _hour + ' : ' + _minute;
        _timeController.text = _time;
      });
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    _timeController.text=currentTime;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var name=customer.first_name+" "+customer.last_name;
    custfNameController.text = name;
    String _chosenValue;
    return WillPopScope(

        onWillPop: () {navigationBar
          moveToLastScreen();
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar:AppBar(),
          body:ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 2.0,
              ),
              TextField(controller: custfNameController,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),

                  textAlign: TextAlign.center),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text("Add New",textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
              ),

              SizedBox(
                height: 2.0,
              ),
              Divider(),
              SizedBox(
                height: 2.0,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: NoteController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 2.0),)),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  minLines: 5,//Normal textInputField will be displayed
                  maxLines: 5, // when user presses enter it will adapt to it
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    this.note.note = value;
                  },

                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: TableCalendar(
                  selectedDayPredicate: (day) {
                    return isSameDay(_selectedDay, day);
                  },
                  onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedDay=selectedDay;
                      String _reminderDate = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(_selectedDay);
                      note.actn_on=_reminderDate.toString();

                    });
                  },// Set initial date

                  focusedDay: DateTime.now(),
                  firstDay: DateTime.utc(2010, 10, 16),
                  lastDay: DateTime.utc(2030, 3, 14),),
              ),

              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Text("Set time",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
                  )),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        _selectTime(context);
                      },

                        child: TextFormField(
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          onSaved: (String val) {
                            _setTime = val;
                          },
                          enabled: false,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          controller: _timeController,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
              ]
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: height*0.03,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Remind me",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),

                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:80.0),
                      child: Container(
                        child: Switch(
                          onChanged: toggleSwitch,
                          value: isSwitched,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                  ],),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children:<Widget>[
                      Text("Priority",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:20.0),
                        child: Container(
                          child: SmoothStarRating(
                            size: height=50.0,
                            allowHalfRating: false,
                            onRated: (value) {
                              this.note.prty=value;
                              print("rating value -> $value");

                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      )]),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: height*0.08,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: 55.0,
                  width: 200,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    elevation: 2,

                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    child: Text('Save',textScaleFactor: 1.5,),
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        _save();
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          floatingActionButton:_speedDial(),
        ));

  }
  void moveToLastScreen() {
    Navigator.pop(context, true);
  }

  void _save() async {
    moveToLastScreen();
    note.cust_id=customer.cust_id;
    print(customer.cust_id);
    print(note.cust_id);
    int result;
    if (note.note_id != null) {  // Case 1: Update operation
      result = await dbService.updateNote(note);
    } else { 
      result = await dbService.insertNote(note);
    }

    if (result != 0) { 
      FormHelper.showAlertDialog(context,'Status', 'Note Saved Successfully');
    } else {
      FormHelper.showAlertDialog(context,'Status', 'Problem Saving Note');
    }
  }
}
```

note_info.dart // This is the screen which displays the listview

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:vers2cts/models/note_model.dart';
import 'package:vers2cts/models/customer_model.dart';
import 'package:vers2cts/services/db_service.dart';
import 'package:vers2cts/utils/db_helper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:vers2cts/utils/form_helper.dart';
import 'new_note.dart';


class Note_Info extends StatefulWidget{
  final String appBarTitle;
  final CustomerModel customer;
  Note_Info(this. customer, this.appBarTitle);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
   return Note_InfoState(this. customer,this.appBarTitle);
  }

}

class Note_InfoState extends State<Note_Info> {
  DBService dbService = DBService();
  List<NoteModel> noteList;
  int count = 0;

  static final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  NoteModel note=NoteModel();
  String appBarTitle;
  CustomerModel customer=new CustomerModel();
  Note_InfoState(this.customer, this.appBarTitle);

  bool rememberMe = false;
  DateTime _date = DateTime.now();
  TextEditingController custfNameController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  updateListView();
    if (noteList == null) {
      noteList = List<NoteModel>();
      updateListView();
    }

    TextStyle titleStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead;
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var name=customer.first_name+" "+customer.last_name;
    custfNameController.text = name;

    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 4,
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.add,

                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => NewNote(customer,note)));
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
            body: Container(
              child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextField(controller: custfNameController,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),

                        textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      child: Row(children: [
                        ImageProfile(customer.cust_photo),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.call,
                              color: Colors.green,
                              size: 45,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {

                            },
                          ),
                        ),

                      ],),
                    ),

                    SizedBox(
                      height: 50,
                      child: AppBar(
                        bottom: TabBar(
                          tabs: [
                            Tab(
                              text: "All",
                            ),
                            Tab(
                              text: "Pending",
                            ),
                            Tab(
                              text: "Cancelled",
                            ),
                            Tab(
                              text: "Completed",
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    // create widgets for each tab bar here
                    Expanded(
                      child: TabBarView(
                        children: [
                          // first tab bar view widget
                          Container(
                              child: getNotecheckList()
                          ),

                          // second tab bar viiew widget
                          Container(

                          ),


                          Container(
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                'Cancelled',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(

                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                'Completed',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 55.0,
                        width: 200,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          elevation: 2,

                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                          color: Theme
                              .of(context)
                              .primaryColorDark,
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          child: Text('Save', textScaleFactor: 1.5,),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              //_reset();
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]
              ),
            )
        ));
  }

  Widget ImageProfile(String fileName) {
    return Center(
      child: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 80.0,
          backgroundImage:  fileName == null
              ?AssetImage('images/person_icon.jpg')
              :FileImage(File(customer.cust_photo))),

    );

  }


  ListView getNoteListView() {

    TextStyle titleStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.subhead;

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: count,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {

        return Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 2.0,
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(this.noteList[position].note, style: titleStyle,),
            //subtitle: Text(this.customerList[position].date),
            trailing: GestureDetector(
              child: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.grey,),
              onTap: () {
                //  _delete(context, customerList[position]);
              },
            ),
            onTap: () {
              //navigateToDetail(this.customerList[position],'Edit ');

            },

          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
  Future<void> updateListView() {
    final Future<Database> dbFuture = DB.init();
    dbFuture.then((database) {
      int cid=customer.cust_id;

      Future<List<NoteModel>> noteListFuture = dbService.getCustomerNotes(cid);
      noteListFuture.then((noteList) {

        setState(() {
          this.noteList = noteList;
          this.count = noteList.length;
        });
      });
    });
  }
  int _isChecked=-1;
  var selectedIndices = [];
  ListView getNotecheckList() {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: count,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
        return Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 2.0,
          child: CheckboxListTile(
            title: Text(this.noteList[position].note),
            subtitle: Text(this.noteList[position].actn_on),
            value: selectedIndices.contains(position),
            onChanged: (_) {
              if (selectedIndices.contains(position)) {
                selectedIndices.remove(position);// unselect
              } else {
                selectedIndices.add(position);  // select

              }
            },
            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                ),
            );
          },
         );
        }
  }

  }
```

note_model.dart

```
import 'model.dart';

class NoteModel extends Model {
  static String table = 'note';
  bool isSelected=false;
  int note_id;
  int cust_id;
  String note;
  String actn_on;
  int rmnd_ind;
  double prty;
  String colr;
  String sts;

  int id;
  String cre_date;
  String cre_by;
  String mod_date;
  String mod_by;
  int txn_id;
  int delete_ind;

  NoteModel({
    this.note_id,
    this.cust_id,
    this.note,
    this.actn_on,
    this.rmnd_ind,
    this.prty,
    this.colr,
    this.sts,

    this.id,
    this.cre_date,
    this.cre_by,
    this.mod_date,
    this.mod_by,
    this.txn_id,
    this.delete_ind
  });

  static NoteModel fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return NoteModel(
      note_id: map["note_id"],
      cust_id: map['cust_id'],
      note: map['note'].toString(),
      actn_on: map['actn_on'].toString(),
      rmnd_ind: map['rmnd_ind'],
      prty: map['prty'],
      colr: map['colr'].toString(),
      sts: map['sts'].toString(),


      id: map['id'],
      cre_date: map['cre_date'].toString(),
      cre_by: map['cre_by'].toString(),
      mod_date: map['mod_date'].toString(),
      mod_by: map['mod_by'].toString(),
      txn_id: map['txn_id'],
      delete_ind: map['delete_ind'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {
      'note_id': note_id,
      'cust_id': cust_id,
      'note':note,
      'actn_on': actn_on,
      'rmnd_ind': rmnd_ind,
      'prty': prty,
      'colr': colr,
      'sts':sts,


      'id': id,
      'cre_date': cre_date,
      'cre_by': cre_by,
      'mod_date':mod_date,
      'mod_by':mod_by,
      'txn_id':txn_id,
      'delete_ind': delete_ind

    };

    if (note_id != null) {
      map['note_id'] = note_id;
    }
    return map;
  }
}
```

db_service.dart

```
import 'package:vers2cts/models/note_model.dart';
import 'package:vers2cts/utils/db_helper.dart';
class DBService {
  Future<int> insertNote(NoteModel note) async {
    await DB.init();
    var result = await DB.insert(NoteModel.table, note);
    return result;
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getNoteMapList() async {
    await DB.init();
    var result = await DB.query(NoteModel.table);
    return result;
  }

  Future<List<NoteModel>> getCustomerNotes(int customer) async {
    await DB.init();
    var res = await DB.rawQuery("note WHERE cust_id = '$customer'");
    int count = res.length;
    List<NoteModel> notelist = List<NoteModel>();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      notelist.add(NoteModel.fromMap(res[i]));
    }
    return notelist;
  }
}
```

db_helper.dart   actn_on saves the date and prty saves the priority

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:vers2cts/models/model.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

abstract class DB {
  static Database _db;

  static int get _version => 1;

  static Future<Database> init() async {
    if (_db != null) {
      return _db;
    }

    try {
      var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
      String _path = p.join(databasesPath, 'CTS.db');
      _db = await openDatabase(_path, version: _version, onCreate: onCreate);
      print('db location:'+_path);

    } catch (ex) {
      print(ex);
    }
  }

  static void onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
 await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE note (note_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,cust_id INTEGER, '
            'note TEXT, '
            'actn_on TEXT, rmnd_ind INTEGER, prty REAL, colr TEXT,'
            'sts TEXT,'
            'id INTEGER, cre_date TEXT,cre_by TEXT, mod_date TEXT,mod_by TEXT, txn_id INTEGER, delete_ind INTEGER)');
 }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> query(String table) async =>
      _db.query(table);

  static Future<int> insert(String table, Model model) async =>
      await _db.insert(table, model.toMap());
 static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> rawQuery(String table) async =>
      _db.query(table);
}
```

Comment: Use query like: `_db.query(table, orderBy: 'cre_date desc')`

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou DarShan I got my answer I just had to use ORDER BY in my query

```
Future<List<NoteModel>> getCustomerNotes(int customer) async {
    await DB.init();
    var res = await DB.rawQuery("note WHERE cust_id = '$customer' ORDER BY actn_on ASC,prty DESC;");
    int count = res.length;
    List<NoteModel> notelist = List<NoteModel>();
    // For loop to create a 'Note List' from a 'Map List'
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      notelist.add(NoteModel.fromMap(res[i]));
    }
    return notelist;
  }
```